# 16 MB size of aggregration pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, spring-data-mongodb

This is about a recommendation on `mongodb`. I have a `collection` that always increase row by row (I mean the count of documents). It is about 5 billion now. When I make a request on this `collection` I sometimes get the error about 16 MB size.

The first thing that I want to ask is which structure is the best way of creating `collections` that increasing the rows hugely. What is the best approach? What should I do for this kind of structure and the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the 16MB limitation is on documents, not collections. Specifically, its the maximum BSON document size, as specified in [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/) in the documentation.

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

If you're running into the 16MB limit in aggregation is because you are using MongoDB version 2.4 or older. In these, the `aggregate()` method returned a document, which is subject to the same limitation as all other documents. Starting in 2.6, the `aggregate()` method returns a cursor, which is not subject to the 16MB limit. For more information, you should consult [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/) in the documentation. Note that each stage in the aggregation pipeline is still limited to 100MB of RAM.

Comment: I use 2.6 version.I still get size error.For example **group** operation is limitted still.

Comment: And why you edit the question ? This is not english grammaire competition,is this ? @Juan Carlos Farah

Comment: Can you show the exact error you are getting and the aggregation query that you're running, as well as a sample document, if possible?

Comment: The link of your answer that you gave me,i have already known it. Tell me another thing that helps me @Juan Carlos Farah

Comment: I'm glad you were aware of it. If you provide some of the information I suggested, I can try to help. Otherwise, it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: I use spring-data mongo driver. In my situation there is a structure with embedded document and a list inside per one document.when i query and use unwind or group operation it throws exceed limit exception.